# Estimating the Mean of a Function of a Stochastic Process

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

My question is about estimating the mean of a function of a stochastic process:

A function $f(X_t, X_{t-1}, ... , X_{t-n})$ takes in a ***fixed*** number of events $X_t, X_{t-1}, ... , X_{t-n}$ from a stochastic process and gives out a number.

Given an observation i.e. an observed sequence of values from the stochastic process $X_t$, how do I estimate the expectation $\mathbb E(f)$?

If I see m observations of the stochastic process, is $\frac{1}{m - n-1} \sum_{t = n+1}^m f(X_t, ..., X_{t-n})$ a valid estimator?

The reasoning would be that, interpreting $f$ as a stochastic process itself with sample paths $f(X_t, ..., X_{t-n})$, the mean can be estimated by simply averaging the observations, but I'm worried that the f values would be highly correlated, but I only use every observation $X_t$ just once, I'm afraid that I'm throwing away information.

This is all very heuristic, what's the proper way to deal with this problem?

In reality, f doesn't really have an interpretation as a stochastic process.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your question is. Integrating or summing up $m$ observations values for $f(X)$ will merely tell you the sum of the probabilities of those $m$ values. It won't tell you the expected statistical process.

If you're looking to identify $E(X)$, then you should follow the standard operating procedure, i.e.,
$$ \int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx = E[x].$$

Comment: I'm trying to find $\mathbb E(f(X_t, X_{t-1}, ... , X_{t-n}))$.

Comment: ... using a sequence of observations from the stochastic process.